# Возврат к предыдущей activity жестом смахивания

Tags: java, android, activity

[image: пример эффекта]

Как добиться подобного эффекта, когда текущая activity следует за пальцем, а под ней видно предыдущую?

Answer (score 6):

В res/anim создаете файлы slide_in_left.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="-50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

slide_in_right.xml:

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

slide_out_left.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-50%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

slide_out_right.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="50%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Теперь кодим:
main activity class:

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        try {
            float slope = (e1.getY() - e2.getY()) / (e1.getX() - e2.getX());
            float angle = (float) Math.atan(slope);
            float angleInDegree = (float) Math.toDegrees(angle);
            // left to right
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > 20 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 20) {
                if ((angleInDegree < 45 && angleInDegree > -45)) {                      
    startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivitiy.this, NextActivity.class); 
    CurrentActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(
        R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
     finish();
    }
                // right to left fling
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > 20
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > 20) {
                if ((angleInDegree < 45 && angleInDegree > -45)) {
    startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivitiy.this, NextActivity.class); 
    CurrentActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(
        R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
     finish();

                }
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

слушатели действий:

```
final GestureDetector  gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
     //the parent layout   
            findViewById(R.id.parent_layout).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) return false;
                    return false;
                }
            });
     //an image view
    findViewById(R.id.image_view).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) return false;
                    return false;
                }
            });
    // a text view
    findViewById(R.id.text_view).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) return false;
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Можно еще посмотреть[тут](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#depth-page).

Comment: С этим кодом текущая activity не следует за пальцем.

Answer (score 2):

Честно говоря это не Android way, но если сильно надо то есть такая либа
https://github.com/ikew0ng/SwipeBackLayout

Comment: С этой либой есть косяки, когда текущую activity тянешь в бок, под ней видно рабочий стол а не предыдущую activity...
И что бы ей воспользоваться наш класс должен расширят SwipeBackActivity, а хотелось бы ActionBarActivity

Comment: Ну всегда можно сделать fork и подправить как тебе надо :)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность ).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, мне добавить пример использования библиотеки ? А если библиотеку удалят ? Получиться мой пример потеряет смысл.